# how do I install phpmyadmin on windows server 2012 from scratch

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation, windows-server-2012

how do I install phpmyadmin on windows server 2012 from scratch?? I dont even know where to begin this. I tried but it didn't work out. What else do I need to install in order to make this work? I do have PHP installed and working. But aside from that, what else do I need? Can someone please help??

Comment: Is this for a production web server?

Comment: On what web server software did you install PHP for? Microsoft IIS? Apache? nginx? lighttpd?

Answer (score 1):

maybe I will forget something, but that's not a "easy-step-by-step-procedure"

STEP 1: you'll need a webserver!

- First of all, Install IIS on your server using "Server Manager" (or apache, if you prefer)
- Second (or maybe first?) get/install a MySQL server to administer
- configure IIS. Well, that's quite complicate to explain here!
- Test IIS (http:// localhost should show you a welcome screen)

STEP 2: PHP!

- Download the last version of PHP (5.x) from here: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5
- Install PHP on IIS (as CGI, if you don't know the difference between the various possibilities)
- Test PHP creating a phpinfo() page

STEP 3: PhpMyAdmin

- Download it from here: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php
- extract the archive in the wwwroot folder (or wherever you want to create your website or folder); in a subfolder maybe? let's call that subfolder "phpma"
- in this "phpma" folder, create a config folder
- copy the config.sample.inc.php file from "phpma" to the "config" folder and rename it to "config.inc.php"
- give the WRITE permission on this file to the user that will execute IIS
- open your webbrowser to http:// server/phpma/setup/
- follow the procedure

Comment: Is there a step missing here? How would IIS know where to point `http://server/phpma` to? Do we need to do something in IIS first before heading to that URL?

Comment: No, if you create the phpma folder in the iis root folder; (Default: c:\ìnetpub\wwwroot)